# nova-compute service State changes every second (UP<->DOWN)

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

the status of my nova-compute service is changed from UP to down every second. This causes instance creation to fail or repeat success.
Please let me know if you need any additional information.
Thank you.

[Compute Service State 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ev3bh.png)
[Compute Service State 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsPiB.png)

Comment: Check the nova-compute, nova-conductor and nova-api log files for corresponding messages.

Comment: This sounds like a rabbitmq issue maybe, check the credentials of the services and rabbitmq logs, too.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the time is out of sync between nodes. Especially if the nodes running nova-api have even minor drifts.

Can you run `date` on all nodes at the same time?